# Java tomcat embedded with Jersey File Upload

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, jersey

I'm building a java application with tomcat embedded and jersey REST.

What i need to do is to implement a VERY simple (and single) file upload inside this application but i can't find anywhere a guide for my context...i just found a file upload solution but NOT with embedded tomcat.

Any suggestions?

Thanks everyone in advice and sorry for my English

Comment: Commons FileUpload should work in embedded just the same as elsewhere?

Comment: I don't think so ...where the uploaded file "should" be saved?the server is embedded so is "inside the jar"

Comment: Even if the *library* is inside the jar doesn't mean your data has to reside inside jar as well?! If you have no disk access at all you'd have to create MemoryFileItem like DiskFileItem maybe...